# Visual Studio folding comments

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, comments

OK I'm trying to add some method documentation to my code. I like the way the .NET authors documented their code but I can't get the folding to work.

In the .NET documentation the method comments are folded just in front of method (see line 288 in picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9TFa.jpg)). When I try an replicate the same behavior the comments get placed on the line above the method (see line 13 in picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9TFa.jpg)).

[image]

On line 13 of my code I have copied the comment on line 288.

[image]

Obviously there is some voodoo going on here. How did they get their comments to not add any vertical lines when folded?

Comment: That's a feature of the Metadata-As-Source syntax generator only.  You should just use XML doc comments.

Comment: The `XML` comments are *much* easier, in C# just type three slashes (`///`) above a method, property, structure, class or other object.

Comment: another option is to use resharper. it will do this for you

Comment: I am away of the three slash (`///`) trick but it still folds the comments to a different line.